# brackets and points order in language c

Tags: c, expression, operator-precedence

### I wonder in language c, is `a.b[i]` is the same thing as `(a.b)[i]` ?

Here **a** is a structure and **b** is his member (**b is an array or a pointer**). 

I read an article about precedence of c operators just now and it told me that the **[ ] (brackets)** operator is prior to the **.(point)**, and the **associativity of these two c operators is left-to-right** :

### So what is the order of the following expression (in c)?

```
a.b.c[i].d[j]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operators `.` and `[]` have the same precedence, and are evaluated from left-to-right. The expression `a.b[i]` is the same as `(a.b)[i]`

The expression `a.b.c[i].d[j]` is evaluated as: `((((a.b).c)[i]).d)[j]`

Comment: This is the article [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), so that it means all the operators of the **precedence 1** have the exactly precedence ?

Comment: @SWIIWII Yes, and the associativity is left-to-right.