# (Seemingly) nonsensical operator precedence when accessing an array member of struct

Tags: c, operator-precedence

A bit of an embarrassing question but I'm confused about operator precedence here:

```
typedef struct {
  char arr[1024];
} SomeStruct;

mySomeStruct.arr[42]
```

Since array access has a higher operator precedence than member access, shouldn't this actually mean `mySomeStruct.(arr[42])`, which just doesn't make any sense; what exactly am I trying to access in `mySomeStruct`? The compiler throws an error if I try `mySomeStruct.(arr[42])`, which checks out.

This implies that what's actually happening is `(mySomeStruct.arr)[42]`, but doesn't this violate operator precedence?

Thanks!

Comment: `.` and `[]` have the same precedence and are evaluated left to right.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh... that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [brackets and points order in language c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565386/brackets-and-points-order-in-language-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Eugene's comment.

`.` and `[]` have the same precedence and are evaluated left to right.